# How to put a worksheet reference in WorksheetFunction.CountA?

Tags: excel, vba, rows, worksheet

I'm getting

> "1004 application-defined or object-defined error"

I need to count rows containing data beginning at Cell("A2") of multiple worksheets.
I tried several combinations.

How do I put this **worksheet("Sheet1")** reference into the instruction?

```vb
Dim oRows As Long
Dim oRows2 As Long
'...

oRows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)))
oRows2 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)))
```

If there's just data in "A2" the following code returns "1048575" instead of "1".

```
oRows = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

So, I need to use CountA function.

Comment: How about  .... Range("A2", Range("A1").End(xlDown))?

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"))-1`?

Comment: Note that [this is the correct approach to find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: The only problem here is that I need to put the " **Worksheets("Sheet1")** " reference into the instruction but I don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

The following will count all cells in column A that are not empty, then subtract 1 for cell A1 if it is not empty:

`oRows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(“A:A”)) - WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(“A1”))`